# How to reverse geocode with maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, leaflet, google-geocoder

I am using **leaflet** to display markers on a map, when I `click` on a `marker`, I get its `lat` and `lng`, then I am sending these to **google maps geocoder** to retrieve the address name:

```
var markerCoords = [];
circle.on('click', function (e) {
    var curPos = e.target.getLatLng();
    markerCoords.push(curPos.lng);
    markerCoords.push(curPos.lat);
    geocodeLatLng();
});

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    function geocodeLatLng(geocoder) {
      var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(markerCoords[1]), lng: parseFloat(markerCoords[0])};
      geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          if (results[0]) {
            console.log(results[0].formatted_address);
          } else {
            window.alert('No results found');
          }
        } else {
          window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
      });
    }
```

But it gives me:

> ```
> Cannot read property 'geocode' of undefined
> ```

**NOTE**

This line is fine

```
var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(markerCoords[1]), lng: parseFloat(markerCoords[0])};
```

As if I do console.log I get the correct `lat` and `lng`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.  You aren't passing the reference to the geocoder into the `geocodeLatLng` function, so it is `null` inside the function:

```
var markerCoords = [];
circle.on('click', function (e) {
    var curPos = e.target.getLatLng();
    markerCoords.push(curPos.lng);
    markerCoords.push(curPos.lat);
    geocodeLatLng(geocoder);  // <============================================== **here**
});

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
function geocodeLatLng(geocoder) { 
  var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(markerCoords[1]), lng: parseFloat(markerCoords[0])};
  geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
  // ... code to process the result
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because google api hasn't loaded yet, you can try loading it before other scripts, to make sure, check `console.log("google api object is", geocoder)` and check Geocode to verify whether google has loaded before calling the api.
Edit : you don't need geocoder as parameter in geocodeLatLng function,as pointed out by @geocodezip, it will be undefined if you don't pass it. Since parameter will get priority over outer scope when variable names are same.

Following procedure will give you the address of user's current position, you can pass any lat, lng and get its address:-

```
//getting location address from latitude and longitude with google api
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
        function success(position) {
                var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                var long = position.coords.longitude;
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
                console.log("google api object is", geocoder)                
                var latlng = { lat: lat, lng: long };
                geocoder.geocode({ 'location': latlng }, function (results, status) {

                    if (status === 'OK') {
                        if (results[0]) {

                       console.log(results[0].formatted_address);// this will be actual full address
                        } else {
                            alert('No results found');
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);

                    }
                });

        }


        function error(err) {
            alert("Allow location services!");
        }
```